# ToggleClass Based on checkbox status

Tags: jquery, css, forms

So I've got some nav that consists of form checkboxes floated next to a traditional anchors. If the corresponding checkbox is not checked, I want to add a class (that basically will be styled to dim the anchor tag). What's the best way to do this systematically?

```
<div id="navPod">
    <form method="post" action="#" id="contentFilterForm" name="contentFilterForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value="<?php echo $q;?>" />
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'projects'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($proj){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="pr" value="1" id="filterProjects" />
        <input class="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'playground'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($playground){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="pl" value="1" id="filterPlayground" />
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'about'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($culture){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="cu" value="1" id="filterCulture" />
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'leadership'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($leadership){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="le" value="1" id="filterLeadership" />
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'careers'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($jobs){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="ca" value="1" id="filterCareers" />

        <input class="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'blog'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($blog){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="bl" value="1" id="filterBlog" />
        <input class="checkbox" <?php if($pagetype == 'home'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($pagetype == 'delicious'){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} if($links){ echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="li" value="1" id="filterDelicious" />

        <input id="refreshSubmit" type="button" value="" onclick="createURLS()"/>
    </form>

    <div class="subnav">
        <a id="projectsLink" title="Projects" href="/projects/" <?php if($pagetype == 'projects'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >Projects</a><br />
        <a id="playgroundLink" title="Playground" href="/playground/" <?php if($pagetype == 'playground'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >Playground</a><br />            
        <a id="aboutLink" title="About Centerline Digital" href="/about/" <?php if($pagetype == 'about'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >About Us</a><br />
        <a id="leadershipLink" title="Leadership" href="/leadership/" <?php if($pagetype == 'leadership'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >Leadership</a><br />
        <a id="careersLink" title="Careers" href="/careers/" <?php if($pagetype == 'careers'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >Careers</a><br />
        <a id="blogLink" title="Blog" href="/blog/" <?php if($pagetype == 'blog'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >Blog</a><br />
        <a id="thoughtsLink" title="Thoughts and Links" href="/thoughts/" <?php if($pagetype == 'delicious'){ echo "class=\"currentPage\""; } ?> >Thoughts and Links</a><br />

        <a target="_blank" title="Subscribe to Custom Feed" id="feedLink" href="/dyn/">Subscribe to Custom Feed</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the html I would try this

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){
var anchor_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('filter','').toLowerCase();;
     $('#'+anchor_id+'Link').toggleClass('someclass', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    var anchor_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('filter','').toLowerCase();;
     $('#'+anchor_id+'Link').toggleClass('someclass', $(this).attr('checked'));
})
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/3Nzmq/)

Comment: Replace your entire if/else block with this: `$('#'+anchor_id).toggleClass('someclass', $(this).attr('checked'));`  Let's keep it DRY in here, people.

Comment: Hmm, a little monkeywrench thrown in here. Another piece of jQuery is intercepting the checked attrib (ez-checked). I've got this '$('.checkbox').change(function(){
        var anchor_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('filter','');
        $('#'+anchor_id).toggleClass('filtered', $(this).attr('checked'));
    })' but the toggleClass is never firing as it's not seeing ever seeing checked as true.

Comment: @Keefer I updated the selector and the event to avoid conflict hopfully

Comment: @mcgrailm Thanks for your help. It's kind of working. I've got this as my code `$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var anchor_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('filter','').toLowerCase();;
        $('#'+anchor_id+'Link').toggleClass('dim', $(this).attr('checked'));
    })` But it's not looking at the initial state of the checkboxes. It takes a toggle off and then on for the class to be added.

Comment: @Keefer do you mean that it doesn't set them at start ? or that it breaks when you set them at start up ?

Comment: @mcgrailm It doesn't add the class for ones that are checked already. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("a[id$='Link']").each(function(){
        var checkboxID = this.id.replace("Link", "");
        checkboxID = "filter" + checkboxID[0].toUpperCase() + checkboxID.substr(1);

        $(this).addClass($("#" + checkboxID).is(":checked") ? "dim" : "");
    })
})
```